# Using worker object for QThread crashes silently or blocks main thread

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I am attempting to make a simple factory function to wrap Python functions in `QThread` to prevent blocking the main application thread when performing long-running noncritical operations in the background (for example caching data).

I have attempted to follow the [popular blog post](https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/) that describes the actual intended usage of `QThread` without subclassing it and overriding `run`. I have been searching for the solutions to my problems for well over half of the day and can't seem to get any sort of thing working, no matter what I try and how. I'm tempted to just do this the "wrong" way and subclass `QThread`. The code for the wrapper follows.

```
from qtpy.QtCore import Slot, Signal, QThread, QObject


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, target, *args, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs

    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
        self.finished.emit()


def create_thread(target, *args, parent=None, **kwargs):
    thread = QThread(parent)
    worker = Worker(target, *args, **kwargs, parent=parent)

    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.run)
    worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

    return thread
```

When using the `make_thread` function passing the `target` without setting the `parent` to the instance of the `QMainWindow`, the `target` function executes and blocks, but then crashes silently after `finished` is emitted. Any `print` calls within the `target` function also fail to print anything to `stdout`.

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

If the `parent` is set, the `target` runs and does print to `stdout` but also blocks the main thread and prevents widgets from becoming visible until `finished` is emitted, leaving the main window hung and blank for the duration.

The example interface I am using simply has a `QLabel` for an example widget that is intended to show immediately while the `target` executes in the background. It does not show until the `target` completes, and then only if `parent` of the `QThread` is specified. Otherwise, the program just crashes (after exactly five seconds, as is shown in the example below). None of this code works in either `PySide2` or `PyQt5`.

```
import sys
import time

from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

import modpack_builder.gui.helpers as helpers


class ExampleMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget()))

        self.label = QLabel("If you see this immediately, the thread did not block.", self.centralWidget())

        self.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.test_thread = helpers.create_thread(self.long_running_task)
        self.test_thread.start()

    @staticmethod
    def long_running_task():
        print("Task started.")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Task finished.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(list())
    window = ExampleMainWindow()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If there are too many tags on this question or if they are redundant please let me know. I can never tell for sure which ones to use.

Comment: Why do you connect `started` to `start` and then `start` to `run`? Just connect `started` to `run` like this: `thread.started.connect(worker.run)`.

Comment: @musicamante I have made the change to the post but the result is still the same.

Comment: Also, the worker is garbage collected, you should return it also and set it as an instance attribute in some way.

Comment: Both of your `thread` and `worker` object have same parent. In that case `worker.moveToThread(thread)` will not move `worker` to the `thread` because its affinity is with the `parent`. Read the [doc](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#moveToThread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider the following:

- If a QObject has a parent then its life cycle depends on the parent, otherwise it depends on python which is handled by the concept of scope.
- A QObject belongs to the same thread as the parent.
- It is not thread-safe that the methods of a QObject are executed in a different thread than the one they belong to, except for the signals.

Considering the above "worker" is a QObject that does not have a parent so python will handle its memory and in this case it is a local variable that will be destroyed after executing the create_thread function. Possible solutions are passing it a QObject as a parent, making it a global variable, making it an attribute of another object that has a larger life cycle, etc.

On the other hand, worker and thread cannot have the same QObject as their parent, since by definition they live in different threads, remember that QThread is not a thread but a thread handler and belongs to the thread where it was created and not to the thread it manages.

If you are going to invoke a method of a QObject from another thread through a signal then use the @Slot decoration.

It is not necessary to use "emit" in the connection between signals.

Considering the above, you can make worker an attribute of the QThread.

```
import sys
import time

from qtpy.QtCore import Slot, Signal, QThread, QObject
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class Worker(QObject):
    start = Signal()
    finished = Signal()

    def __init__(self, target, *args, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.__target = target
        self.__args = args
        self.__kwargs = kwargs

        self.start.connect(self.run)

    @Slot()
    def run(self):
        self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
        self.finished.emit()


def create_thread(target, *args, parent=None, **kwargs):
    thread = QThread(parent)
    worker = Worker(target, *args, **kwargs)
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.start)
    # or
    # thread.started.connect(worker.run)
    worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
    thread.finished.connect(thread.deleteLater)

    thread.worker = worker

    return thread


class ExampleMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget()))

        self.label = QLabel("If you see this immediately, the thread did not block.",)

        self.centralWidget().layout().addWidget(self.label)

        self.test_thread = create_thread(self.long_running_task)
        self.test_thread.start()

    @staticmethod
    def long_running_task():
        print("Task started.")
        time.sleep(5)
        print("Task finished.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(list())
    window = ExampleMainWindow()

    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Should I ever worry about what `parent` should be set to for the `Worker` and the `QThread`?

Comment: @spikespaz Your question is too broad but I think that if you analyze what it indicates in my answer then you will know

Comment: Well, I should clarify. It is clear to me by your first three bullets that the `Worker` should not have a parent, and instead assigning it as an attribute of the `QThread` is the way to go to satisfy the first point while not causing problems because of your second. But what about the `QThread` specifically? I did read and understand your answer; don't worry, I'm not the type to copy and paste code without understanding it. I shouldn't have asked about the parent of `Worker` because you already make it clear.

Comment: @spikespaz 1) I did not point out that the Worker should not have a parent but should have it then it should live in the same thread, but in your case it is not necessary to have a parent 2) A QThread is also a QObject so the first bullet is also applied point. 3) The concept of "parent" of a QObject is used in C++ for the memory management of pointers, and in python that concept is extrapolated so that the memory of the QObjects depend on the parent and not on python.

Comment: I apologize that I still do not completely understand. Should the `QThread` be an orphan, and be the parent of the `Worker`? Or should the `QThread` have a parent of the `QMainWindow` or whatever creates it, and the `Worker` be an orphan that is assigned to the `QThread`? And if the `Worker` should have a parent for garbage collection purposes, but the `QThread` exists in the same thread of its parent, that should the parent of the `Worker` be to avoid it living in the main thread? What is the most correct thing to do here, and why? Again, sorry. I'm not familiar with these concepts.

Comment: Also, you say that in this case the `Worker` does not need a parent. In what situation would this be required?

Comment: @spikespaz Many questions that I am not going to answer I am just going to point out clear concepts: 1) Who do you want to manage memory? If you want it to be Qt then pass it a parent, if not, then make python handle the memory (I recommend then reading the concept of scope applied to python), 2) If you want to set a parent to a QObject then the rules must comply to point to in the bullets. 3) there is no strict rule, everything depends on you. That analysis is what I did in the remaining part of my answer.

Comment: @spikespaz Please, read: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html, https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html and https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html

Comment: Why would setting the `QThread`'s parent cause it to block the parent in PySide2 and not PyQt5?

Comment: @spikespaz I don't see this behavior in PySide2 5.15 on Linux, are you using the latest version of PySide2?

Comment: My lockfile says I am using PySide2 5.15.0. I am using Windows at the moment, this program is cross-platform.

Comment: @spikespaz In order not to cause confusion, I suppose that in your previous comment you indicated that you are placing something like: `self.test_thread = create_thread(self.long_running_task, parent=self)`, if so and it generates that problem, then it is probably a bug since according to the docs it should not happen, if so, I recommend reporting it